# Python-Django LiveSettings; ImportError: No module named controb.adminrest_framework

Tags: django

I am working on a Python-Django app where I have a requirement to be able to change database settings by the user without using settings.py.

I searched the web and found a module named LiveSettings which allows changing the database settings through an admin interface.

I installed LiveSettings and did what was stated in the Installation section of the module. But when I run "python manage.py syncdb", it gives me the following error:

ImportError: No module named controb.adminrest_framework

Is there anyone who has used this module and can help me fix this issue?
Or is there any other module that I could use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show the full traceback containing the error? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it was some syntax error, I forgot to add a , between the apps name in INSTALLED_APPS.

Thanks very much for your prompt response @alexce